# Sorting a list out with several parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I have spent the whole afternoon trying to figure this out... but I can't! I have a DataFrame that needs to be sorted in a specific way. This is from census data in the US. I have first reduced the list by filtering through county level (SUMLEV = 50). I think that's the only part of the code I got right (I think). Then I need to grab the three most populous counties for each state. However, I do not need all the states to display. Those three values representing the most populous counties will have to be summed to display the three most populous states based on the three most populous counties. Phew! Sorry for the long explanation. Here's the code:

```
SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION    STATE   COUNTY  STNAME  CTYNAME CENSUS2010POP   ESTIMATESBASE2010   POPESTIMATE2010 ... RDOMESTICMIG2011    RDOMESTICMIG2012    RDOMESTICMIG2013    RDOMESTICMIG2014    RDOMESTICMIG2015    RNETMIG2011 RNETMIG2012 RNETMIG2013 RNETMIG2014 RNETMIG2015
0   40  3   6   1   0   Alabama Alabama 4779736 4780127 4785161 ... 0.002295    -0.193196   0.381066    0.582002    -0.467369   1.030015    0.826644    1.383282    1.724718    0.712594
1   50  3   6   1   1   Alabama Autauga County  54571   54571   54660   ... 7.242091    -2.915927   -3.012349   2.265971    -2.530799   7.606016    -2.626146   -2.722002   2.592270    -2.187333
2   50  3   6   1   3   Alabama Baldwin County  182265  182265  183193  ... 14.832960   17.647293   21.845705   19.243287   17.197872   15.844176   18.559627   22.727626   20.317142   18.293499
3   50  3   6   1   5   Alabama Barbour County  27457   27457   27341   ... -4.728132   -2.500690   -7.056824   -3.904217   -10.543299  -4.874741   -2.758113   -7.167664   -3.978583   -10.543299
4   50  3   6   1   7   Alabama Bibb County 22915
```

And this the code I started (gives an error):

```
census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].groupby('CTYNAME')['STNAME'].apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some usable sample data:

```
   SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION  STATE  COUNTY   STNAME         CTYNAME  CENSUS2010POP
0      40       3         6      1       0  Alabama         Alabama        4779736
1      50       3         6      1       1  Alabama  Autauga County          54571
2      50       3         6      1       3  Alabama  Baldwin County         182265
3      50       3         6      1       5  Alabama  Barbour County          27457
4      50       3         6      1       7  Alabama     Bibb County          22915
5      50       4         5      6       7  Florida      Miami-Dade          44567
```

The Code:

```
df = df[df['SUMLEV']==50].sort_values(by='CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False).groupby('STATE').apply(lambda x:x.head(3))

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False)

df.head(3)
```

Output

```
   STNAME          CENSUS2010POP
0  Alabama         264293
1  Florida          44567
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the sample data. I didn't know how to make it look in place. I tried using the code you provided but there's one parameter missing: choosing only the three most populous states based on the three most populous counties. Would be most grateful for the help :)

Comment: Updated to meet the requirements